# How to make sidebar stick only interms of height?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position

Trying to create a side navbar with fixed position (only for height)

Tried fixed position, but it overlaps with the content.
Created sidebar using this 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar

```js
<div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            padding: "20px",
            width: "20%",
            background: "black",
            height:"100vh",
            position:"fixed",


          }}
        >
```

I exepect the navbar to be fixed, but not overlap other content.

Comment: in case of `fixed`, the element is removed from the normal page layout and no space will be created for it. Hence other content would flow behind it. You need to create a space. If the navbar is fixed on the left, you might need to provide margin left with same width as container for the one overlapping below.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `document.body.style.marginLeft = "20%";`. If sidebar is on left

Comment: that will make the content overflow

Answer (score 0):

add flex: 1 on sidebar then flex 2 on the remaining divs after it.

sample code:

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <div style="flex: 1"> This is sidebar </div>
  <div style="flex: 3"> This is content </div>
</div>
```

the number in the flex pertains to the width of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below css and check, as inner div is generated dynamically i applied css by using child selector

```css
        #root > div > div:first-child{
            padding: 10px;
            width: 40%;
            background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
            height: 100vh;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #root > div > div:nth-child(2){
            flex: 1 1 0%;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 58%;
            margin-left: 41.5%;
        }
```